# How to get APNS token from fcm token?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I have implemented push notifications via FCM and have to implement a third party product that uses apns for notifications, is there any way I can work with both at once, how can I get the apns token along with fcm token?

Comment: It explained better here -> [ALs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50344633/firebase-cloud-function-messaging-with-apns-token-rather-than-fcm-token)

Comment: I couldn't understand, can you please explain it a little bit here?

Comment: So you can do the apns native integration in that way you will get the apns key but as per your requirement you also need FCM key. So you can use  https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1:batchImport api to converts apns into FCM. Also I would recommend to use two different key in your backend database for apns and fcm. (Here is the documentation link: https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#create_registration_tokens_for_apns_tokens)